# Dnsmasq running in ubuntu virtual box guest

Tags: dnsmasq

I am trying to install a DNSmasq server in an ubuntu virtualbox machine. I set it a static IP with a bridged network interface. The host has also another static IP. The DNSmasq config sends DNS servers to the clients when the IP is requested and also the router IP to access to the Internet. My intention is disable DHCP in the router and use only this DNSmasq server for any internal machines including phones connected to my network.
The problem is that when I disable the DHCP server in the router all network stops and nobody gets an IP from the virtual machine. As the setup is very simple I think that maybe the issue is related to the bridged interface network I set in the virtual machine.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: You’ll need to define this DNS server on each host. But first, can you `ping` it from each host? If not, it won’t be able to resolve DNS queries for those hosts until you resolve that issue.